# Connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4001 N|Solid

Tags: node.js, nsolid

I just downloaded the N|Solid **runtime**, **hub** and **console**. I then managed to start the **hub** without any error, but when I try to launch the **console**, or if I try to execute any **nsolid-cli** command, I'm just facing this error :

```
NODE_DEBUG=nsolid NSOLID_HUB=127.0.0.1:4001 npm start
NSOLID 11582: registering default commands
NSOLID 11582: nsolid initializing
NSOLID 11582: nsolid initialized on port 49738

> nsolid-console@1.1.8 start /home/ubuntu/nsolid_dl/nsolid-console-v1.1.8-linux-x64
> NODE_ENV=production node bin/nsolid-console --interval=1000

NSOLID 11595: registering default commands
NSOLID 11595: nsolid initializing
Server running on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NSOLID 11595: nsolid initialized on port 57195
NSOLID 11600: registering default commands
NSOLID 11600: nsolid initializing
NSOLID 11600: send system_info undefined undefined
NSOLID 11600: sending http://localhost:9000/system_info
NSOLID 11600: nsolid initialized on port 49811
Error trying to connect to N|Solid: Error: "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4001"
[Error: query exited with code: 1]
```

More precisely, no N|Solid tool seems to be able to connect to 127.0.0.1:4001

It must probably be a silly problem, but I just can't get it.
I would be very thankful to you if anyone found what I'm missing here !

But firstly, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure you start `etcd` before starting the **hub**.

You can run it using the following command:

```
$ [sudo] etcd -name nsolid_proxy -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:4001 -advertise-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:4001 -initial-cluster-state new
```

2. Set the `NSOLID_SOCKET` env var to `0.0.0.0:0` when running your application:

`$ NODE_DEBUG=nsolid NSOLID_HUB=127.0.0.1:4001 NSOLID_SOCKET=0.0.0.0:0 npm start`

If you need more information you can visit our [documentation](https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/1.0/docs/installing-the-hub#verifying-the-nsolid-hub-installation) regarding the hub

Comment: It looks like it's working ! I think I'm beginning to figure out how N|Solid is working at its core, but maybe reading through the whole documentation might help me ^^' Thank you very much for your help !